# Generate multiple Android apk with multiple URL configuration

Tags: android

Is there any way to generate multiple Android build with multiple Server URL configuration. We want to provide build to 3 customers. Is it possible to generate for that 3 customers with 3 different Server URL. I don't have any idea to do this. Please let me any idea to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below uses buildTypes but, you could do similar with [productFlavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) (This seems more like what you need):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "DOMAIN", '"release.example.com"'
    }
    develop {
           ...
        buildConfigField "String", "DOMAIN", '"develop.example.com"'
    }
    staging {
            ...
        buildConfigField "String", "DOMAIN", '"staging.example.com"'
    }
}
```

And then in your code you could do BuildConfig.DOMAIN. Remember BuildConfig will be generated after compilation and also use the one from your application package (com.example.BuildConfig)

Comment: I was typing the same kind of answer. I would suggest to add the Build Variants documentation : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html